# I am a beginner and i have a question, why cant this return me anything when i call this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Something(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
       return (number // 2) 
    elif number % 2 > 0:
        return (3 * number + 1)
Something(12)
```

I did it with and without parenthesis

Comment: The function did return a value (it would have been 6) but you didn't do anything with that value.  If you want to see what was returned, collect it into a variable and then `print` that variable.  Like `value = Something(12)` followed by `print(value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your function is returning a value and if you run this directly in your terminal you will see the result displayed in standard out.

Note that the integers modulo 2 is `{0,1}`. Also, idiomatic python uses snake_case.

Furthermore, you can take advantage of the truthy/falsey nature of this set.

I've rewritten your example to show you what I mean:

```
def number_mod2(number):
    #if odd
    if number%2:
        return 3*number+1
    #if not odd (all other cases) 
    return number // 2
#outputs `6`
print(number_mod2(12))
```

Answer (score 0):

It likely is returning a number but you need to put the function in a print to have it outputted.

```
def Something(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
       return (number // 2) 
    elif number % 2 > 0:
       return (3 * number + 1)
print(Something(12))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code and the output return a number (6)